# Sync stopwatch runtime duration over a socket

Tags: android

Currently have stopwatches running on multiple devices that are kept in sync via a socket server. When a device starts the stopwatch it sends a message to the socket server, and the other clients listening see this and also start their stopwatch. There is not a huge amount of latency so it's not a big deal that while they are running the times are slightly off from each other.

However when "pause" or "stop" is pressed we want to have that final time shown on the pausing clients device to also be the same time shown on all devices.

Currently here is what happens when the timer is stopped/paused:

```
long time = Long.parseLong(message);
mChronometer.setBase(time);
```

The message being sent is from the code here:

```
this.sendWebRequestStopTimer(mChronometer.getBase())
```

While this does cause the time to be adjusted, it is slightly off usually by less than a second, typically 100-400 milliseconds. I assume this is because the each device has a slightly different time despite same NTP servers.

So in short, is there a better way to adjust the code so that the child devices will display the exact same time as the parent device (one who hit pause)?

Note: Any of the devices can play/pause/stop the stopwatch. No one device is in charge of controlling this stopwatch function. So `device 1` could start the timer, `device 2` could pause it, and `device 3` could resume it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the device that presses pause/stop send its time to the server, and echo that to all other devices.  There's really no other way of doing it, short of a hard wired dedicated network.  And even that would still leave you with some discrepancy in the 10s of ms range.  Of course this could cause some of the devices to show a smaller number, looking like it went back in time.  No real way to avoid that.

Comment: It really doesn't matter for it to be in sync real time, we just want it so that whenever it is paused or stopped it displays the same time on all devices. It does not matter if there is a network delay at all here, we really just want to update the time the stopwatch is showing so that it is the same as the parent device.

Comment: @ComputerLocus That's reasonable doable then.  Just have the master send the time it reads to the server, and push that value to the other devices with the stop message